# Fatal Error Message Received

Tags: php, fatal-error

I loaded up our site to take a look at it but it is coming up blank. I made some modifications the the index.php file to show the error and this is what I've received:

```
Fatal error: Method Varien_Object::__tostring() cannot take arguments in /chroot/home/vpwindow/[domain name]/html/lib/Varien/Object.php on line 488
```

I'm not sure what to do from here. Any help would be great!

Comment: Which version of magento you have loaded? I think its the php version problem.. Kindly share the php version and magento version.

Comment: If you are using lower version of magento(1.3 and less) with higher version of php(5.3 or more) then refer these links : http://pravams.com/2011/05/31/magento-fix-for-fatal-error-method-varien_object__tostring-cannot-take-arguments/ and http://support.createhosting.co.nz/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=67

Comment: Thank you so much for the references! It worked!!!! Please answer the question and I'll up vote it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference links to resolve this issue :

http://pravams.com/2011/05/31/magento-fix-for-fatal-error-method-varien_object__tostring-cannot-take-arguments/

and

http://support.createhosting.co.nz/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=67

Cheers :-)